# Hexagon cutted edges on html5 video

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

What I'm trying to figure out is how to make a `html5` video`(mp4)` to have `hexagon edges`. My video size is `900x600` and it is a square, i am try in to make it a hexagon instead.

anyone could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of.. You can make a hexagon shape in css and stick it on top, but that will of course cut off some of your video.

Edit: What I meant previously was that he  could either edit the video or something like that because you wont get a perfect hexagon in css. Anyway, here's your solution:

Making use of `:before` and `:after` https://jsfiddle.net/rckndxbx/

Comment: I want the hexagon part to cut the video part out to be fair, any idea how can i achieve this then?

Comment: Cutting off part of the video is a given, how many cameras do you know that have a hexagonal output

Comment: I didnt clear myself clear enough, I want the hexagon cuts also cutting the video..

Comment: You will also need to set the z-index of it, and make a container div that hides the rest of the video. The inside of the hexagon is transparent.

Answer (score 1):

> You can do it by using simple css

```
video{
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
```

this will show your video as hexagonal in shape.
to understand it better follow the link [clipping video](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)
For any query comment it.
All the best.